# Laravel 5.4 Show results belonging to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to show the results that are assigned to a user, the logic is that in the administration the user sees only what is assigned.

I have my model in the following way, where in the scopeName function I try to pass the data of the admins and proposals tables to the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Proposal extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'proposals';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'admin_id', 'prefix', 'order', 'title', 'province_id', 'municipalities', 'address', 'description', 'status', 'comments', 'closing_comments', 'institution_id', 'table_id'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function userid()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function admins()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
    }

    public function adminId()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'admin_id');
    }

    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        $query->join('admins', 'proposals.admin_id', '=', 'admins.id')
              ->select(
                'proposals.*',
                'admins.name as admin_name',
                'admins.last_name as admin_last_name',
                'admins.area as admin_area',
                'admins.job_title as admin_job_title',
                'admins.email as admin_email',
                'admins.phone as admin_phone',
                'admins.movil as admin_movil')
              ->where('proposals.order','like',"%$name%")
              ->orWhere('proposals.title','like',"%$name%");
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $data = Proposal::name($request->get('criteria'))->where('admin_id','=',Auth::id())->orderBy('id','asc')->paginate(5);

  return view('administracion.propuestas.inicio', compact('data'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

The error in the view it throws is the following:

```
(2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admins.last_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `proposals`.*, `admins`.`name` as `admin_name`, `admins`.`last_name` as `admin_last_name`, `admins`.`area` as `admin_area`, `admins`.`job_title` as `admin_job_title`, `admins`.`email` as `admin_email`, `admins`.`phone` as `admin_phone`, `admins`.`movil` as `admin_movil` from `proposals` inner join `admins` on `proposals`.`admin_id` = `admins`.`id` where (`proposals`.`order` like %% or `proposals`.`title` like %%) and `admin_id` = 1 order by `id` asc limit 5 offset 0)
```

Comment: On your method scopeName you forgot to return the $query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the admins table whether you have a last_name field. If not, then

```
public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        $query->join('admins', 'proposals.admin_id', '=', 'admins.id')
              ->select(
                'proposals.*',
                'admins.name as admin_name',
                'admins.area as admin_area',
                'admins.job_title as admin_job_title',
                'admins.email as admin_email',
                'admins.phone as admin_phone',
                'admins.movil as admin_movil')
              ->where('proposals.order','like',"%$name%")
              ->orWhere('proposals.title','like',"%$name%");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct I had not noticed that simple detail, that is the effect of low levels of caffeine.